# windows server 2003 - how to give rights for PowerUser for Services

Tags: windows-server-2003, service, permissions

I have 6 windows servers 2003. However only 2 of them - when I connect to them as PowerUser - let me to open Services and manage them.

When I would log in to the server as Administrator, what I should change to to allow PowerUser to access Services. I could not find any security rights panel/window on Services.

Answer (score 2):

There are several methods to do this. I prefer to use subinacl for smaller deployments:

Ex: SUBINACL /SERVICE \MachineName\ServiceName /GRANT=[DomainName]UserName[=Access]

See the MS KB here for more details: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325349